# Using LocationListener within a fragment

Tags: android, fragment, locationmanager, locationlistener

Can I get a users location by using LocationListener and `LocationManager` from within a fragment? Or do I need to use the `LocationListener` from within the underlying activity and use an interface (or some other method) to transfer the data back to the fragment? I am in the process of converting an activity to a fragment due to a change app UI. Getting location was no problem when I was using standalone activities, however, I cannot get any location returned now that I have made the activity into a fragment.

Below is how I am adding the LocationListener. It is declared earlier on as LocationListener locationListener.

```
private void addLocationListener(){
    locationListener = new LocationListener(){

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            GeoPoint userLoc = processNewLocation(location);
            if(userLoc != null){
                Log.d("USERLOC", userLoc.toString());
                                    //do something with the location    
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            locationManager = (LocationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
            } else {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            locationManager = (LocationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
            } else {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    };
}
```

NOTE: processNewLocation just converts the location to a GeoPoint. It's not even getting that far because no location is ever obtained.

Here's the code registering the listener with the location manager

```
public void addLocationManager(){
locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
}

private void getLocationFromNetwork(){
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_REFRESH_TIME, LOCATION_REFRESH_DISTANCE, locationListener);
Log.d("GET NETWORK", "Listener registered");
}

private void getLocationFromGPS(){
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_REFRESH_TIME, LOCATION_REFRESH_DISTANCE, locationListener);
Log.d("GET GPS", "Listener registered");
}

private Location getLastLocation(){
Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
return lastKnownLocation;
}
```

Comment: you can use LocationManager & LocationListener from within a fragment.  Probably more code is needed to figure out why your not getting a location.

Comment: start by posting code for your locationListener.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you posted above, you don't ever register the `LocationListener` with the `LocationManager`.  You need code like this from your `onProviderEnabled` code somewhere in the `Fragment` creation code:

```
locationManager = (LocationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
} else {
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
}
```

The `onProviderEnabled` callbacks won't occur until after you register with the location manager.

Comment: there was some code earlier showing the locationListener being registered.  apparently it was removed when adding more code.

Comment: I can post it again sorry - the comment asked just for the location listener code